# Using \foreach with \SplitArgument

Tags: foreach, xparse, optional-arguments, arguments

Why does the \test command not split the argument when called from a foreach loop?

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ >{\SplitArgument{3}{|}} m }{\printtest#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printtest}{mmmm}{
    (#1,#2)\quad s_{\IfValueT{#3}{#3}}\IfValueT{#4}{#4}}

\newcommand{\looptest}[1]{
   \foreach \n in {#1}{
       $\test{\n}$\\
    };

$\test{1|1}$\\       % this works
$\test{2|2|1}$\\     % this works
$\test{3|3|2|'}$\\   % this works
$\test{4|4|3|''}$\\  % this works

\looptest{1|2|1, 3|7|2, 6|7|3, 6|5, 9|5|3|''} % this does not
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments are not expanded timely. Every foreach spin argument is still inside a brace pair. Also don't use whitespace inside the foreach arguments. It might cause pattern mismatches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ >{\SplitArgument{3}{|}} m }{\printtest#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printtest}{mmmm}{(#1,#2)\quad s_{\IfValueT{#3}{#3}}\IfValueT{#4}{#4}}
\newcommand{\looptest}[1]{\foreach\n in{#1}{$\expandafter\test\expandafter{\n}$\\}}

\begin{document}\noindent
$\test{1|1}$\\       % this works
$\test{2|2|1}$\\     % this works
$\test{3|3|2|'}$\\   % this works
$\test{4|4|3|''}$\\  % this works
\looptest{1|2|1,3|7|2,6|7|3,6|5,9|5|3|''} % this does not
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This uses a `listofitems` approach to parse the input to `\looptest`.  The introductory `\setsepchar{,}` sets the parsing character as `,` . The macro `\readlist*\looplist{#1}` parses the list into a `\looplist[<index>]` array (while ignoring blank spaces around the `,` delimiters), which is then sequentially accessed with a `\foreachitem` loop.  However, the loop argument `\n` must be expanded once on its way to being digested by `\test`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,xparse,listofitems}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ >{\SplitArgument{3}{|}} m }{\printtest#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printtest}{mmmm}{
    (#1,#2)\quad s_{\IfValueT{#3}{#3}}\IfValueT{#4}{#4}}

\newcommand{\looptest}[1]{%
   \setsepchar{,}%
   \readlist*\looplist{#1}%
   \foreachitem \n \in \looplist{%
       $\expandafter\test\expandafter{\n}$\\
    }
}

\begin{document}\noindent
$\test{1|1}$\\       % this works
$\test{2|2|1}$\\     % this works
$\test{3|3|2|'}$\\   % this works
$\test{4|4|3|''}$\\  % this works

\noindent\looptest{1|2|1, 3|7|2, 6|7|3, 6|5, 9|5|3|''} % this does not
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a way to totally eliminate `pgffor` and `xparse`, doing it completely within `listofitems`.  Note that stray blank spaces may be introduced not only around the list commas `,` but also around the `|` separators, with no ill effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\test[1]{%
  \setsepchar{{|}}%
  \readlist*\testlist{#1}%
  \def\temp{\printtest}%
  \foreachitem\testitem\in\testlist{%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\expandafter{\testitem}}%
  }%
  \temp\relax\relax\relax%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\printtest[4]{(#1,#2)\quad s_{#3}#4}
\newcommand{\looptest}[1]{%
   \setsepchar{,}%
   \readlist*\looplist{#1}%
   \foreachitem \n \in \looplist{%
       $\expandafter\test\expandafter{\n}$\\
    }%
}
\begin{document}\noindent
$\test{1|1}$\\       % this works
$\test{2|2|1}$\\     % this works
$\test{3|3|2|'}$\\   % this works
$\test{4|4|3|''}$\\  % this works

\noindent\looptest{1|2|1, 3|7|2, 6|7|3, 6|5, 9|5|3|''} % this does not
\end{document}
```